# Why vision lift Thor's hammer in avengers?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

Thor hammer cannot be lifted by anyone except Thor but in movie *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, vision lifted the hammer (Mjolnir) of Thor not any other avengers even when all the avengers are strong?

Comment: Question title says **why**, but question body has **how**. How being duplicate and Why is not a duplicate